# Count rows with and combine them with math operator

Tags: sql

I have a table with different events for a case. I want to calculate how many times event A occurs for each case but subtract the amounts of event B

[image: Data sample]

[image: How i want the result to look]

I have started with a code like this, but it does not work.

```
SELECT 
    ((SELECT
        case_id,
        Count(*) 
    from database
    where event = "A"
    Group by case_id)

    - 

    (SELECT
        case_id,
        Count(*) 
    from database
    where event = "B"
    Group by case_id)) as count,
case-id,

from database
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: `database` is a very, very bad table name. (A database usually consists of many tables.)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want conditional aggregation:

```
select case_id,
       ( sum(case when event = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) -
         sum(case when event = 'B' then 1 else 0 end)
       ) as diff
from database
group by case_id;
```